# Delphi - What means the error code 126

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I'm making a web browser using dcef (delphi chromium embedded framework), but afer install and make the program, an error message appears: "Could not find cefvcl". So, I've included the library patch to RAD Studio and tried to compile again, but I have another error: "Could not find the especified module (in application) Error code: 126".
It happens also with c++ builder... I don't know what I must to do...

Comment: "Could not find cefvcl" - run SysInternals ProcessMonitor, set filter to log file activity of your application and of dcef exe and look for not-found results, you would probably see what file was missed and in which folders Windows tried to find it.

Comment: @Arioch, there's no need to search for a solution this way. It is well known "mistake".

Comment: @TLama you have the fish already, TopicStarter can benefit from having a rod and next time he would catch the fish himself, not depending  upon forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [Win32 error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx). Specifically:

> **ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND**
>
> 126 (0x7E)
>
> The specified module could not be found.

Looks like you are missing a DLL.

Generally when you face this error you can debug it using the debugger. Arrange for the debugger to break on exceptions. The call stack should lead you back to the call to `LoadLibrary` that failed.

In the case of the problem being further down the library dependency chain, use a tool like Dependency Walker in Profile mode to work out which dependency is failing to resolve.

In your case I guess you are just missing the CEF DLLs.

Comment: However, when I dowloaded the CEF it cames with the full pack...
I must to copy and paste the /bin/ foler to the project.exe directory?

Comment: The best policy is to have the required DLLs in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Thanks for the help...
I've copied the dlls for the .exe file and my project works now!

Comment: You asked "What means the error code 126?" I think I answered that, right? In which case you might consider accepting.

Comment: Yes, I understood, I just want to know what is the meaning of this code to find how to solve my problem...
So, now I know how to solve this problem in some cases...
Thanks...

Comment: "Looks like you are missing a DLL."
Here is what I want to know...
So, Ive found the dlls from this module and copied to the release folder...

Comment: Er, did you mean to say more?

Answer (score 1):

Copy all the .dll files from the component folder to your project folder. Example
if your project is 32bit copy all the dll files in `dcef3-master\bin\Win32` to the .exe file of your project.

This was answered in one of the comments of a answer. I Just added it as an answer because not a lot of people read the comments

Comment: Yes, I realised it when David said that "The best policy is to have the required DLLs in the same directory as the executable.".

Comment: Yeah but not a lot of people read the answer comments so I thought it might be worth it to add it as an answer.